# Vue Draggable Next - Save Order of Lists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two lists who's order I want to save to local storage and retrieve in order to have their order persist between sessions. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#save) in my Vue 3 TS based project. Below is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Array 1</h3>
    <draggable
      class="items"
      :list="arr1"
      group="items"
      @end="onEnd"
      @change="log"
      :move="onMove"
      animation="300"
      easing="cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)">
      <div
      v-for="item in arr1"
      :key="item.name">
      {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </draggable>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Array 2</h3>
    <draggable
      class="items"
      :list="arr2"
      group="items"
      @end="onEnd"
      animation="300"
      easing="cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)">
      <div
      v-for="item in arr2"
      :key="item.name">
      {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, proxyRefs } from 'vue';
import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'os-draggable',
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  components: {
    draggable: VueDraggableNext,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newItem: '',
      arr1: [
        { name: 'Item 1'},
        { name: 'Item 2'},
        { name: 'Item 3'},
        { name: 'Item 4'},
        { name: 'Item 5'},
        { name: 'Item 6'},
        { name: 'Item 7'},
      ],
      arr2: [
        { name: 'Item A'},
        { name: 'Item B'},
        { name: 'Item C'},
      ],
      order: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onEnd(ev: any) {
      console.log(`onEnd ev: ${ev}`);
    },
    onMove(ev: any) {
      console.log(`onMove ev: ${ev}`);

      const order = [];
      order.push(ev.relatedContext.list);

      window.localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(order));
    },
    log(ev: any) {
      console.log('log: ', ev);
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('order')) {
      if (window.localStorage.getItem('order')) {
        this.arr1 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('order')!);
      }
    }
  },
  deactivated() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(this.order));
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped lang='scss'>
@import 'draggable';
</style>
```

While an element in `arr1` is being dragged, the event object from the `onMove` method creates an array (`ev.relatedContext.list` line 82).

Despite setting my local storage item to be equal to this array, it instead sets it as the array BEFORE the move occurs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

By changing `onMove` to:

```
onMove(ev: any) {
      this.order = ev.relatedContext.list;
    },
```

... and `onEnd` to:

```
onEnd() {
      window.localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(this.order));
    },
```

and finally the `created()` method to:

```
  created() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('order')) {
      this.arr1 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('order')!);
    }
  },
```

... everything ends up working properly for the first array.

Stepwise, we utilize our empty array as a placeholder whenever an element is moved. That way if multiple elements are moved in a single session, `this.order` will be updated each time. When the drag event ends, we commit `this.order` to local storage for the next time someone visits the page. Finally, when the component is created we check to see if our local storage key exists, if it does we set `arr1` to be equal to it. `arr1` is the list that the draggable component draws from.